# Animating Swipeable Component: React Native Gesture Handler

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I want to add animations to my `Swipeable` component in order to make it clear to the user that it can be swiped. However, I don't want the animation to fully open the action items. I only want it to open partially and then return to the starting position. Is there a way to achieve this? Can I control the swipe programmatically, so that I can animate it with Reanimated?

The closest thing I could find in the docs is the `openLeft` and `openRight` methods, but again, I don't want to swipe my component the entire way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this workaround:

```
<Swipeable
  renderRightActions={() => (
  <View style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}} />
  )}>
  {children}
</Swipeable>
```

to make the `Swipeable` work, and then inserting an absolutely-positioned background below it. This way, I could wrap the `Swipeable` with an `Animated.View` and the background will stay stationary as it is being animated.
Of course, there might be an ideal solution I'm missing.

Comment: hope there was a solution, but I've done exactly the same